# Достаточно ли защищена админка?

Tags: cookie, авторизация, защита, админка

Здравствуйте, информации по авторизации админа на сайте и защите от взлома - over 9000. Однако я все равно не понимаю, к чему такие сложности? Концепция моя проста:

1. Если не установлены сессионные переменные и куки, то Админ вводит логин и пароль в форму (число попыток - 10)
2. Данные кодируются **определенным** образом и сверяются с md5-данными в БД (или даже прописаны в файле - это не важно)
3. В случае успеха, `$_SESSION['admin']` устанавливается в значение **true**
4. Куки-переменная `$_COOKIE['admin']` также принимает значение **true** с длительностью жизни, допустим, неделя, чтобы в течение недели админ не напрягался с вводом логина и пароля.

Имеет ли такая технология авторизации право на жизнь? В чем может заключаться опасность применения такого метода?

Comment: Я собрал самолёт. Взял крылья, забавные круглые крутящиеся штуки под фюзеляж положил. Верно ли я его собрал?

Comment: А что происходит после 10 попыток?

Comment: @PashaPash - полный обрыв связи))) Админу приходит новый пароль на ящик и **ссылка**, по которой можно перейти для восстановления доступа. Ничего нельзя сделать. Белый экран и надпись: _проверьте почтовый ящик_

Comment: @TheDoctor, вопрос состоял в том, как можно выкрасть у админа всего 2 куки - phpsessid и admin? Или каким другим образом можно получить доступ к админке?

Comment: Информационная безопасность - огромный пласт IT, его ну никак нельзя выразить через пару кук, стащив которые, можно получить полный доступ. Так же нет данных о возможных атаках на 2 шаг, 1 - вообще никак не описан, ибо как ты будешь попытки считать? Или всем, даже админу запретишь входить после 10? Неа, тут в двух словах не объяснишь всё, даже в десяти.

Comment: @TheDoctor, попытки считаются в файле с ограниченным доступом- обычный декремент значения)). Это уже работает на сегодняшний день. Почему куки? Злоумышленник может ввести более 10-ти паролей и вся админка **блокируется вообще от любого посягательства**, кроме Админа - у него куки установлены не менее чем на неделю. Ясно, буду менять структруру...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить, потому что вы просите провести аудит того, чего мы не видим. Был замечательный пример PHP-эксплойта: пришедший со стороны пользователя хэш на смену пароля сверялся с аналогичным в базе. Новый хэш можно было сгенерировтаь повторным запросом пароля. Так как он генерировался с помощью md5, то с вероятностью что-то около 1/256 этот хэш имел первыми двумя символами `0e`. В этот момент злоумышленник осуществлял запрос, передавая строку `0` вместо хэша, PHP приводил обе части сравнения к числу, и получал успешный результат; таким образом брутфорс занимал в среднем всего 256 запросов, что, при должном серваке и сети, можно успеть за секунду. Из-за того, что не видны все подробности системы, можно лишь прокомментировать вышесказанное, а не дать оценку защищенности системы.

> (число попыток - 10)

Это - хороший шаг, но эта система должна работать безотказно, чтобы не получилось так, что пользователь банится, осуществляя десятую попытку спустя сутки, час, десять минут. Это - защита от брутфорса, от десятков запросов в секунду; если эти запросы приходят с интервалом в десять секунд - это человек, и там уже не отличишь пользователя от отчаянного ручного брутфорсера.

> md5

md5 крайне прост для перебора, и использовать его не рекомендуется. Есть Blowfish и SHA-512.

> Куки-переменная $_COOKIE['admin'] также принимает значение true с длительностью жизни, допустим, неделя, чтобы в течение недели админ не напрягался с вводом логина и пароля.

**Этого делать нельзя**. Я вручную могу проставить себе любые куки. Если система принимает какие-либо решения на основании этой куки, а не сессии, то вся ваша система уже скомпрометирована.

**Причем сессия угоняется точно так же**, потому что завязана на куки. Привязывайте авторизацию не просто к булеву значению в сессиии, а сверяйте айпишник, как минимум. Я не знаю, меняет ли хром User-Agent в процессе своего обновления, например, но по-хорошему авторизация должна быть завязана на максимуме информации о пользователе.

Comment: Сессия же не хранится на клиенте. Максимум только если злоумышленник уведет sessionID.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Если вы думаете, что нужно что-то большее, то нет - злоумышленник поставит себе куку PHPSESSID с этим значением, и получит чужую авторизацию.

Comment: вопрос в том, как он получит это значение? Перебором?

Comment: Достаточно сидеть в той же вай-фай сети.

Comment: Имеете в виду, что он будет снифферить?

Comment: Да, почему бы и нет.

Comment: Легче из-за плеча пароль подглядеть :) Снифферить сетку - мне кажется это слишком геморройно.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, сейчас существуют практически бесконечные авторизации.

Comment: бесконечные авторизации? Что Вы имеете в виду? Меня вообще сильно волнует этот вопрос, и я бы его с удовольствием обсудила бы, но в рамках stack overflow это ведь не приветствуется. .. Может в чат?

Comment: у нас есть [флуд-рум](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23460/flood-room) для всякого такого. Если вкратце, хром хранит сессионные куки бесконечно, поэтому вероятность увидеть пароль меньше, чем успешно заснифать другие ручки.

Answer (score 1):

Злоумышленник просто ставит куку `admin = true`, и заходит без ввода имени и пароля.

Злоумышленник тупо делает постоянный ввод непрвильного пароля. Админ получает кучу писем со ссылкой, и не может войти. Как только восстанавливает пароль - его опять блокирует.

Comment: 1. Админ всегда может войти, потому что у него куки определены как true, даже если на его почте уже новый пароль.

Comment: Любой может подделать куки

Comment: Может я просто не могу поставить куку admin в true? Я переходил из разных браузеров, мне не удалось выставить куку admin и войти в админку.

Comment: @Etki, там сессия стартует изначально, по-моему, куку admin не так просто подделать, мне лично не удалось.

Comment: Через интерфейс браузера, через JS, через любую программу, которая может общаться с сетью - можно поставить куку. Вариантов - мильён.
Вот поэтому люди дошли до токенов - рандомных строк, вместо `true`.

Comment: @Xor, почему вы думаете, что если вам не хватило квалификации подделать куку, то у потенциального зловреда ее нет? Я вручную в блокноте могу написать запрос с этой кукой.

Comment: @Etki, придется снять вопрос. Спасибо всем. На самом деле, меня снова обманул Денвер! В денвере **не получается** подделать куку. Только что я попробовал на хостинге - элементарно!

Comment: @Xor, Сильно сомневаюсь что сервер хоть как-то может помешать/помочь, ибо куку ставит клиент. Но пожалуйста :)

Comment: @TheDoctor, вопрос я задал, потому что работаю на Денвере. В любом браузере есть расширение, которое позволяет устанавливать куки. В том то все и дело, что на Денвере это невозможно было сделать. А на реальном хосте я только что взломал собственную админку! Спасибо за внимание! ))) Буду переходить на токены или на нечто другое!

Comment: @Xor т.е. когда я написал что злоумышленник может просто проставить куку - вы не поверили? :))

Comment: @PashaPash,конечно поверил! Я уже описывал выше, что мне этого не удавалось проставить хакерскую куку, потому что на Денвере не было такой возможности. По сути, вопрос только из-за этого и задан был. Я не мог понять, почему мне не удается подделать admin=true, а теперь все ясно. На реальном сервере это работает. Я нашел выход из положения. Технология осталась та же, только куки генерируется сервером раз в 5 дней немыслимо отвратительной длины с рандомным набором символов.)))